# How to add Gcloud consoles' IPs into organization policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've had to add an organization policy that restricts access to the cloud for anyone. Only are allowed : the IP adresses that I've explicitely granted.

Example : Try to log in from an unauthorized external IP, you'll get a "Access blocked" screen when trying to access the organization via `console.cloud.google.com`.

The problem is now I cannot seem to make the simplest `gcloud` calls within the console.

For example : `gcloud projects list` returns :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  metadata:
    method: google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.Projects.ListProjects
    service: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED
```

via
When I try to authenticate to the account that is owner on the organization via `gcloud auth application-default login`. I get

```
ERROR: Access was blocked due to an organization policy, please contact your admin to gain access.
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) (access_denied) Account restricted
```

<s>Is this because the gcloud is called from the console, that has an external and/or internal IP that isn't listed in the organization policy?</s>

How do i resolve this considering my organization policy? How do I determine which kind of IPs to allow (internal vs external)?

EDIT :

I have confirmed it is an IP blockage problem since I can call `gcloud projects list` within a local terminal of an authorized IP adress

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to configure private google access seeing as you've implemented an org policy that restricts external access.

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access.

Comment: Not sure that this is adaptable to a project not part of a subnet... but I will check it out thanks

Comment: If you use the "--log-http" option on the gcloud command you can see clearly the api calls the command is making.  You either need to make sure these get routed internally or look at some other way of achieving this.